# Back to previous url after changing location hash

Tags: javascript, angularjs

My code is:

```
 $rootScope.$on("$locationChangeSuccess", function () {
                    if( $location.$$path.startsWith('/room/') ){
                        $location.hash('container');
                        $anchorScroll();
                    }                    
                });
```

On my `room` pages, the view is scrolled to where I have the element with ID `container`. However my URLs are having `#container` appended to them during the scroll and my back button stopped working.

Whenever I go on `example.com/#/room/123`, I'm redirected to `example.com/#/room/123#container` and my back button then points to `example.com/#/room/123`. So, each time I hit back, the URL goes back to `example.com/#/room/123` and then the above code runs and adds the hash to the code.

Any way to prevent this from happening and keep the back button functional?

Comment: Are you using the built-in Angular router?

Comment: I'm using [$routeProvider](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/provider/$routeProvider)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following [Drazen's tip](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32417798/1370034), I managed to sort the issue by replacing

```
$location.hash('container');
```

with

```
$location.hash('container').replace();
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `location.replace("#container");` instead.

Comment: Nope, that doesn't work. The code inside  `"$locationChangeSuccess"` is run but I get redirected back to the index page.

Comment: `location.replace` should add the hash without altering history.I gathered that was your problem.

Comment: I don't want the hash(if possible). I tried using `location.replace()` but I no more get my scroll.

Comment: Have you tried `$location.replace` instead? "If called, all changes to $location during current $digest will be replacing current history record, instead of adding new one." https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$location#replace

Comment: Managed to get it to work with `$location.hash('container').replace();` . Thanks!